# datatable warning 4 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am working on datatable and facing this error :

> DataTables warning: table id=table - Requested unknown parameter '0'
>   for row 0, column 0.

I have studied this [link](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4) and it says that my table column defines in HTML doesn't match with the columns received from server. BUT in my case both are same.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<table id="table" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead style="background-color:#303641;">
        <tr>
            <th>aNumber</th>
            <th>bNumber</th>
            <th>cellID</th>
            <th>dateTime</th>
            <th>duration</th>
            <th>imei</th>
            <th>imsi</th>
            <th>operatorId</th>
            <th>mscId</th>
            <th>fileId</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Datatable javascript code :

```
var dataTable = $('#table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "iDisplayLength": configData,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: ['colvis', 'print', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'],
    searching: false,
    language: {
        buttons: {
            colvis: 'Show/Hide Columns'
        }
    },
    "ajax": {
        url: "getAdvanceCallAnalysisData.json",
        data: function(d) {
            return $.extend({}, d, {
                "offset": 0,
                "newRequest": newReq,
                "totalRecords": total,
                "lookInCol": "aNumber",
                "lookInVal": "43543543",
                "fromDate": from_date,
                "toDate": to_date,
                "callingCellId": "",
                "CalledCellId": "",
                "cdrType": "",
                "smsType": "",
                "durationFilter": "",
                "selectColumns": "",
                "sortCol": "",
                "sortType": "",
            });
        },
        type: "POST",
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            total = data.responseJSON.recordsTotal;
            newReq = 0;
            test(total, newReq);
            $("#loading_image").hide();
            $(".show_datatable").show();
        },
        "aoColumns": [{
            "mData": "aNumber"
        }, {
            "mData": "bNumber"
        }, {
            "mData": "cellID"
        }, {
            "mData": "dateTime"
        }, {
            "mData": "duration"
        }, {
            "mData": "imei"
        }, {
            "mData": "imsi"
        }, {
            "mData": "operatorId"
        }, {
            "mData": "mscId"
        }, {
            "mData": "fileId"
        }]
    }
});
```

you can see that my columns name and numbers match with the columns define in ajax response.
I have done same thing for another table and it was working fine but it shows error here. don't know why !!

json response : (It returns 15 records, I posted only two just to make it short)

```
{"msg":null,"code":null,"status":null,"data":[{"aNumber":"343","bNumber":"3434","cellID":"410-01-831-14770","dateTime":"2017-08-23 17:27:54.0","duration":419,"imei":"22380831696837","imsi":"35340311428389","operatorId":4,"mscId":"5","fileId":"4"},{"aNumber":"3434","bNumber":"5656","cellID":"410-07-1314-28271","dateTime":"2017-08-23 22:02:15.0","duration":785,"imei":"49776303943255","imsi":"35722667519554","operatorId":1,"mscId":"2","fileId":"5"}],"draw":1,"limit":1000,"recordsFiltered":12,"recordsTotal":12}
```

The most funny part is it shows the correct records and pagination even it display correct rows (with empty data) in datatable. This ajax call returns 15 records. Please see the image below :
[image]

Any idea, what is wrong here ?

Comment: did you refer to datatables.net documentation?
 https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4 they seem to give you a step-by-step guidance to solve this exact issue.

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned in my question that I followed the link you provided. BUT I didn't understand the solution

Comment: console.log your data on complete(), i did a codepen and it seems to be working fine when passing the object you posted https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXKPYR i have a feeling you are not passin in the correct object.

Comment: `console.log(data)` in complete function return `data :[object Object]`

Comment: lovely, `console.dir(data)` then.

Comment: Well, The issue is resolved, I was using `aoColumns` in ajax call, I posted it outside the ajax call and it worked.